# Secondary channels url

Tags: youtube

In the YouTube app, a channel's page has a number of tabs

```
Home Videos Live Playlists Community
```

There seems to be a regression and the `Channels` tab has disappeared.

Can someone give me the url to this, please? I've tried `https://www.youtube.com/<channel name>/channels`.

Comment: Do you have an example page to test this on? I found the channels list for the one I checked (it's no longer a link though) but it may be because the owners set it up like that.

Comment: @Laurel `Home` tab goes to this url https://www.youtube.com/@InternetHistorian/featured `Live` tab goes to this url https://www.youtube.com/@InternetHistorian/streams there's no longer any `Channels` tab, so I'm trying to get the url for it

Comment: Just scroll down. There is an Other Channels section.

Comment: Oh, they moved it to the bottom, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has reduced the number of tabs recently. Tabs with no content are being hidden, the About tab now is a section above the tabs, and the channels tab is rolled into the home tab (which is how things used to be a few years ago anyway).

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFNavbkn6hU) by YouTube's Creator Insider channel announced that change.